# PHP, PDO Count on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, count, pdo

I am trying to get a count of items with PDO (on a MySql table). I read somewhere that the rowCount does not work on MySql. Is this correct?

So far I definitely can't get it to work as I keep getting count=0.

Could anyone give me an idea so I can avoid going back to the db every time? I have multiple queries that look similar to this one:

```
    $items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr ORDER BY $sortBy DESC");
    $count = $items -> rowCount();
    $items -> execute();
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ... }
```

I want to try to avoid an extra query with `SELECT COUNT (*)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to *first* `execute` the query. Only then will the database do its work and only then can you get a count of the found results.

Answer (score 2):

As, @deceze indicated,

```
$items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr ORDER BY $sortBy DESC");
$items -> execute();
$count = $items -> rowCount();
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

`rowCount` only works after `execute`.  I have never had a problem with `rowCount` in MySQL.

Using `rowCount` is nice, but you could also use your own counter variable if you're going to iterate over the results anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add this is all, please refer to the PHP documentation:

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Particularly:

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

And an example from said page:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit WHERE calories > 100";
if ($res = $conn->query($sql)) {

    /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
  if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) {

        /* Issue the real SELECT statement and work with the results */
         $sql = "SELECT name FROM fruit WHERE calories > 100";
       foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
           print "Name: " .  $row['NAME'] . "\n";
         }
    }
    /* No rows matched -- do something else */
  else {
      print "No rows matched the query.";
    }
}

$res = null;
$conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code so much if you are using PDO, such as:

```
$items = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM item_descr ORDER BY $sortBy DESC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($items))
{
    // You can count the array to see how many records you got and you can iterate trough it using foreach / for loops 
}
else 
{
    // 0 records returned
}
```

There is no need for prepared statements in this particular case or checking whether you got any rows back using `rowCount`. It is true that `rowCount` CAN fail even with MySQL, it all depends whether you are using unbuffered queries or not.

Comment: Using a one-liner such as that means you're pumping all the data immediately into a PHP array and therefore into memory all at once. That may be a huge performance problem, depending on the amount of data.

Comment: I didn't say it's good or bad, it's based on what OP asked - sure, it definitely **IS** a potential hole, however it's due to the query itself and not underlying PHP code.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
$my_query = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM the_table');
$c = $my_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

return $c->Count;
```

Answer (score -1):

PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows only affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.

For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.